# Deserialising JsonObject into C# object not working

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I'm connecting into a 3rd party service and getting a JsonObject response that looks similar to the following:

```
    [
    {"header":{"names":["test.1","test.2","test.3","test.4","test.5","test.6"]}}
    ,
    {"name":"test.1","can":"transfer?"}
    ,
    {"name":"test.2","can":"transfer?"}
    ,
    {"name":"test.3","can":"transfer?"}
    ,
    {"name":"test.4","can":"transfer?"}
    ,
    {"name":"test.5","can":"transfer?"}
    ,
    {"name":"test.6","can":"register"}
    ]
```

So, using RestSharp and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`<T>`(response.Content) where `<T>` is RootSearch; I'm using the following C# models to try and deserialize the json into a C# object:

```
    public class RootSearch
    {
        public List<SearchShim> Results { get; set; }
    }


    public class SearchShim
    {
        [JsonProperty("header", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public SearchHeader AllUrls { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("can", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Can { get; set; }
    }


    public class Search
    {
        [JsonProperty("name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("can", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Can { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchHeader
    {
        [JsonProperty("names", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<string> Names { get; set; }
    }
```

But keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'blah.RootSearch' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

I originally tried with SearchShim looking like:

```
 public class SearchShim
    {
        [JsonProperty("header", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public SearchHeader AllUrls { get; set; }

        public list<Search> Details { get; set; }
    }
```

But kept getting the same error.

Now I'm stumped. I must be missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried to set the property names to lower case? 
public string Name { get; set; } => public string name { get; set; }

Comment: The third party response body is an array, not an object.  Does this work? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootSearch>(response.Content[0])`

Comment: Well, no that's not going to fully work either.  Since that response is an array of differing objects I think you're going to have to manually cobble the object graph together using multiple calls to DeserializeObject()

Comment: @Gumbo Yep, the JsonProperty attributes are there to get the lower case names from the JSON results.

Comment: @squillman Arrgh! I thought you were so close with your suggestion. Turns out response.Content[0] throws a compiler error before we even get near that. I've tried adding a [JsonArray] attribute to RootSearch and that did nothing either :(

Comment: Try this: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootSearch.Results>(response.Content)

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to Deserialize the object?

Comment: Try your first approach with : *var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
... JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.content, settings);*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is the fact that you are trying to deserialize into RootSearch, instead you should deserialize into

```
List<SearchShim>
```

and this is the correct object

```
public class SearchShim
{
    [JsonProperty("header", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public SearchHeader AllUrls { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("can", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Can { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noah. I would have thought it would be the same as RootSearch, but I guess it would just look like a single container to the deserializer. Nicely done!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `SearchShim` to this:

```
    public class SearchShim
    {
        [JsonProperty("header", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public SearchHeader AllUrls { get; set; }

        public List<Search> Searches {get;set;}

    }
```

Comment: Sorry Johan, I tried that to start with (bottom of the question above) and its still the same error

Comment: Yep, sorry mate, I missed that part it seems. It looks like the reason why it is choking is due to your json not being consistent. The first item is `header` and the rest are all `name`.